# Cloudfront Distribution Wont Accept New SSL Certificate

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I uploaded a reissued new multi-domain certificate via IAM, but when I access the CDN and check the cert, it still has the old cert with the old domains.

Tried so far:

- I tried clearing the browser cache, tried different browsers, changed my DNS provider
- Went into Cloudfront to change the SSL cert in the distribution settings and waited until it correctly deployed twice

I still receive the old certificate as if there is another SSL cert cache.

Preferably I would like to avoid to reissue the cert and deploy a new distribution and change cdn.domain.com to cdn2.domain.com

Comment: I will try going back to default SSL and then deploy changes, then change back to new cert

Comment: Do you remember how you ended up resolving this?

Comment: I'm in the same boat, changed certificate, still old showing up when accessing the front URL.